# Heating is not working on DIY Dr Cool Mini Split

Tags: hvac, mini-split

I recently installed a 3rd Gen 24k BTU DIY Dr Cool Mini Split Heat Pump, but I'm not able to get the heat working. The indoor unit does cool, but it doesn't doesn't do anything when I switch to heat mode. I've tried the heat mode when it's relatively cool outside (lowest it gets is about 55F here), and I've been told it should start up under 66F.

However, the least sign of operation in heating mode is the outdoor unit spooling up and then shutting off about a minute later. The DIY Mr Cool tech I talked to says he's never seen cooling working, but not the heating. Just to note, I used to get a PC04 `inverter compressor drive error`, when i turned on heating, but that went away after I remade the connections to the compressor. I couldn't see any kinks in the refrigerant lines. I do remember when I opened the valves for the wider line there sounded like an escape of gas, but i was also told this was normal.

Does anyone have any ideas?

I've recorded a short video of the problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5AoG_cficqI&ab_channel=ForgottenLegendsOfTomorrow